# Subbing Gradients for Flat Colors in Zurb-Foundation Elements

Tags: css, colors, zurb-foundation

In trying to convert existing sites to zurb-foundation 4, I find that I need to use gradients rather than flat colors in the top bar (and other elements) in order to recreate the existing design.  That said, many sub-elements base their colors on the color of the top bar, either lightening or darkening it.  So it fails to build.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can use a gradient background for zurb-foundation elements that ship with flat color backgrounds?

Comment: I guess the first thing that would be nice to know is, are you using SASS/SCSS with this Foundation swap?

Comment: We are using SASS/SCSS